Why do the Trisolarans have to come to Earth and not any other planet?
Why do the Trisolarans have to come to Earth and not any other planet?
Does it explain anywhere the reasoning behind this decision? I mean, why come to Earth and fight rather than taking an uninhabited planet and terraforming it? They have vastly superior technology, and it seems very illogical to travel 400 years away to a planet that you're in doubt about winning from the local inhabitants.
Wouldn't it make more sense to try and settle in the closest stable system instead?

Earth's solar system is the closest stable system. They know it's inhabitable. They aren't aware of any other planets that are inhabitable much less terraformable in the timeframe they have to work with. It's Earth or nothing. (I've only read the first book.)

The Tri-Solarans have not found any other planets. Their region of the galaxy is relatively sparse and finding another habitable planet on their doorstep is surprising and unexpected, but highly welcome given how hostile their own planet is to civilised life.
At the point that they launch their fleet they can move at only a fraction of lightspeed. It will take hundreds of years to reach Earth and anything father away would have just been unrealistically inaccessible.

“That is a great accomplishment, as far as I understand it, but it
still seems too slow for interstellar flight.”
“The journey of a thousand miles begins with the first step. The key
is finding the right target.”
“What’s the fleet’s destination?”
“A star with planets about four light-years away—the closest star to
the Trisolaran system.”

Their stated intention is to spread Tri-Solaran civilisation, referring to their fleet as an expedition.

The joyous cry subsided. The people of Trisolaris mutely gazed as their hope gradually shrunk in the western sky. They would not know the outcome of the launch in their lifetimes, but four or five hundred years from now, their descendants would receive the news from a new world, the beginning of a new life for Trisolaran civilization. Wang stood with them, silently gazing, until the phalanx of a thousand stars shrank into a single star, and until that star disappeared in the western night sky. Then the following text appeared: The Trisolaran Expedition to the new world has begun. The fleet is still in flight.…

Note that this is somewhat of a ruse. The aliens are in fact malevolent.

Everyone in the Battle Command Center saw the message in their eyes, just like Wang Miao’s countdown. The message flashed into existence for only two seconds and then disappeared, but everyone got it. It was only a single sentence: You’re bugs!


I'm puzzled.  If the Tri-Solarans are so technologically advanced, and if we humans are already cataloging star systems with possibly-habitable planets — even to the point of working out atmospheric compositions, likely amount of available water, rocky or gassy cores, and temperature ranges — then surely the Tri-Solarans must have taken notice of the Sol system a long time before the events of this story?  This strikes me as a bit of a breakdown in the worldbuilding, but maybe I'm missing something?

@EiríkrÚtlendi - It's a question of eggs and baskets. What happens if they get there and find no habitable planet? Or worse, a habitable planet occupied by an even more advanced society keeping quiet.

I appreciate the thought. This still bothers me as a worldbuilding flaw, though: even at our current level of technology, we are already getting images of exosolar planets, just using the totally passive (and thus undetectable) technique of looking at incoming electromagnetic radiation (i.e. light etc.). This can answer the question of "are there any potentially habitable planets" before physically sending anything (or anyone).

For a society urgently in need of another planet, I'd expect any nearby Goldilocks Zone planets to be the subject of intense observation. With advanced EM collection tech, I'd also expect the Trisolarans to have noticed humanity's profligate broadcasting; at a bare minimum, they would have noticed lights on the night side of the planet. Some US cities have had streetlights since the 1700s; electric streetlights were first installed in 1880.
